# Polynomial word problems

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Find all points on the circle $x^2 + y^2 = 9$ that are 3.5 units from $(4,5)$

and

Find the point on the circle $x^2 + y^2 = 9$ that is closest to $(4,5)$.

I only need to set both x and y to a common variable -- then I can use a graphing calculator to find the results.

Comment: Why "polynomial word"? The title doesn't make sense to me...

Answer (score 1):

For the first problem solve these 2 equations:
$$x^2 + y^2 = 9 $$
$$(x-4)^2 + (y-5)^2 = 3.5^2 $$

For the second problem solve these 2 equations:
$$x^2 + y^2 = 9 $$
$$4y=5x$$

Comment: Thanks. I think I learned another approach - by using a graphing calculator to find the minimum (closest to the circle). Any idea how to do that?